# Override Devise::TwoFactorAuthenticationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, device

I need to override some methods in `Devise::TwoFactorAuthenticationController` from [this](https://github.com/Houdini/two_factor_authentication/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/two_factor_authentication_controller.rb) repository but I cannot find a way of doing that.

I tried to create `two_factor_authentication.rb` file in `config/initializers/` and try to override this way:

```
Devise::TwoFactorAuthenticationController.class_eval do
 def name_of_the_method_you_want_to_override
   code
 end
end
```

But changes in this class are not affecting `Devise::TwoFactorAuthenticationController`

Comment: try to put the changes in the `lib` folder. you might also want to require the `two_factor_authentication_controller` class as well.

Answer (score 1):

I tried standard any device controller overriding way
created:

```
app/controllers/administrators/two_factor_authentication_controller.rb
```

edited routes:

```
devise_for :administrators, controllers: {
    two_factor_authentication: 'administrators/two_factor_authentication' 
  }
```

then tested:

```
class Administrators::TwoFactorAuthenticationController < Devise::TwoFactorAuthenticationController
  def show
    binding.pry
  end
end
```

And it worked